# Marking Items on Apache Solr Search as downloaded based on user viewing

Tags: solr, drupal-7

We have a drupal 7 site that uses Apache Solr search.

We have a number of search pages that use Facet API where users can browse our thousands of images and look for ones to download.

We want for items that have been previously downloaded by the browsing user to be marked as "already downloaded" so they can easily see what they have and don't as they browse.

What's the best way to approach this? Do we alter the actual Apache Solr index? Do we use ajax / javascript to come on top and mark the downloaded items? Or should we set about creating some kind custom Solr filter for "show/hide already downloaded items"?